# Shorthand Combined Functions

Tags: code-golf, math, parsing

I was doing some investigation into trig functions using compound angles recently, and noticed that the results are really long and tedious to write:
$$
\cos(A+B) = \cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B \\
\cos(A-B) = \cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B \\
\sin(A+B) = \sin A \cos B + \sin B \cos A \\
\sin(A-B) = \sin A \cos B - \sin B \cos A \\
$$
$$
\tan(A+B) = \frac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B}
$$
$$
\tan(A-B) = \frac{\tan A - \tan B}{1 + \tan A \tan B}
$$

Realising this, I devised a shorter, golfier way, of writing such expressions:

```
<direction><operator>[functions](variables)
```

Where `direction` is either `«` or `»` and `operator` is in the string `+-*/`

---

Also, when there is more variables than functions, the variables are, in a sense, left shifted through the functions, with unused variables simply being concatenated to the expression:

```
»-[f,g](x,y,z)
```

Turns into:

$$
f(x)g(y)z - f(y)g(z)x - f(z)g(x)y
$$

*Note that the variables `x`, `y` and `z` are left shifting through the functions*

---

Note that when there is only one function given, it is applied as if the expression was an algebraic expansion. For example:

```
«+[cos](a,b)
```

Turns into

$$
cos(a) + cos(b)
$$

---

For an expression like `«+[f, g, h](foo, bar, baz)`, each function in the function list (`f, g, h`)  is applied to every variable, as if the expression was being algebraically expanded:

```
f(foo)f(bar)f(baz)
g(foo)g(bar)g(baz)
h(foo)h(bar)h(baz)
```

These expressions are then concatenated with the provided operator (when the operator is `*`, the expressions are simply concatenated without any symbols):

```
f(foo)f(bar)f(baz) + g(foo)g(bar)g(baz) + h(foo)h(bar)h(baz)
```

---

For an expression like `»+[f, g, h](foo, bar, baz)`, each function in the function list (`f, g, h`) is applied to the variables in sequence, as if the variables were "shifting" through the functions:

```
f(foo)g(bar)h(baz)
f(bar)g(baz)h(foo)
f(baz)g(foo)h(bar)
```

These expressions are once again concatenated using the above method:

```
f(foo)g(bar)h(baz) + f(bar)g(baz)h(foo) + f(baz)g(foo)h(bar)
```

### Some Clarifications

When the direction is `»` and there are more variables than functions , the following method is applied:

```
FOR j = 0 TO length of functions
 FOR i = 0 TO length of variables
  IF i >= length of functions - 1 THEN
   Result += variables[i]
  ELSE
   Result += Functions[i] + "(" + variables[i] + ")"
 NEXT i
 Left shift variables
 Result += operator
NEXT j
```

Given the expression `»-[f,g](x,y,z)`, this would turn into:

```
f(x)g(y)z - f(y)g(z)x - f(z)g(x)y
```

Empty function lists should return an empty expression, as should empty variable lists.

When there are more functions than variables and the direction is `»`, simply ignore the functions in the functions list whose index is greater than the length of the variables list. For example, given `»+[f,g,h](x,y)`:

```
f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(x)
```

### The Challenge

Given a shorthanded string as described above, output the expanded expression

### Test Cases

```
Input -> Output
«+[cos,sin](a,b) -> cos(a)cos(b) + sin(a)sin(b)
»+[cos,sin](a,b) -> cos(a)sin(b) + cos(b)sin(a)
«[f](x,y,z,n) -> f(x)f(y)f(z)f(n)
«+[f](x,y,z,n) -> f(x) + f(y) + f(z) + f(n)
«+[f,g]() -> 
»*[f,g]() ->
»-[f,g](a,b) -> f(a)g(b) - f(b)g(a)
»[g,f](a,b) -> g(a)f(b)g(b)f(a)
«+[tan](a,b) -> tan(a) + tan(b)
»+[](a,b) -> 
»-[f,g](x,y,z) -> f(x)g(y)z - f(y)g(z)x - f(z)g(x)y
«/[f,g](x,y,z) -> f(x)f(y)f(z) / g(x)g(y)g(z)
«[]() ->
»[]() -> 
»+[x,y](foo,bar,baz) -> x(foo)y(bar)baz + x(bar)y(baz)foo + x(baz)y(foo)bar
»+[f,g](x) -> f(x) + g(x)
«+[f,g](x) -> f(x) + g(x)
»+[f,g,h](x,y) -> f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(x)
```

Let it be known that:

- The direction will *always* be given
- The operator is *optional*
- The `[]` denoting the functions will always be present, but will not always contain functions
- The `()` denoting the variables will always be present, but will not always contain variables
- Functions can be outputted in any order just as long as the expressions are in order (`cosAsinB - sinAsinB` can be written as `sinBcosA - sinBsinA` but not as `sinAsinB - cosAsinB`)
- Variable names can be of any length
- The `«` and `»` can be taken as `<` and `>` if wanted (`«` and `»` are preferred however)

Therefore, if no functions/variables are present, then an empty output is required. Whitespacing within the answer doesn't matter (i.e. newlines/extra spaces don't invalidate outputs).

Input can also be taken as:

```
[direction, operator, [functions], [variables]]
```

In which case, `direction` will be a string, `operator` will be either an empty string or an operator, `functions` will be a (sometimes empty) list of strings, as will variables.

### Score

This is code golf, so fewest bytes wins. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Leaderboards

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
# Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the leaderboard snippet:

```
# [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=194719;
var OVERRIDE_USER=8478;
var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;function answersUrl(d){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(d,e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+e.join(";")+"/comments?page="+d+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){answers.push.apply(answers,d.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],d.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var f=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(f),answers_hash[f]=e}),d.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(d){d.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),d.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=function(){var d=String.raw`h\d`,e=String.raw`\-?\d+\.?\d*`,f=String.raw`[^\n<>]*`,g=String.raw`<s>${f}</s>|<strike>${f}</strike>|<del>${f}</del>`,h=String.raw`[^\n\d<>]*`,j=String.raw`<[^\n<>]+>`;return new RegExp(String.raw`<${d}>`+String.raw`\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?`+String.raw`(${e})`+String.raw`(?=`+String.raw`${h}`+String.raw`(?:(?:${g}|${j})${h})*`+String.raw`</${d}>`+String.raw`)`)}(),OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;function getAuthorName(d){return d.owner.display_name}function process(){var d=[];answers.forEach(function(n){var o=n.body;n.comments.forEach(function(q){OVERRIDE_REG.test(q.body)&&(o="<h1>"+q.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var p=o.match(SCORE_REG);p&&d.push({user:getAuthorName(n),size:+p[2],language:p[1],link:n.share_link})}),d.sort(function(n,o){var p=n.size,q=o.size;return p-q});var e={},f=1,g=null,h=1;d.forEach(function(n){n.size!=g&&(h=f),g=n.size,++f;var o=jQuery("#answer-template").html();o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",h+".").replace("{{NAME}}",n.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",n.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",n.size).replace("{{LINK}}",n.link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o);var p=n.language;p=jQuery("<i>"+n.language+"</i>").text().toLowerCase(),e[p]=e[p]||{lang:n.language,user:n.user,size:n.size,link:n.link,uniq:p}});var j=[];for(var k in e)e.hasOwnProperty(k)&&j.push(e[k]);j.sort(function(n,o){return n.uniq>o.uniq?1:n.uniq<o.uniq?-1:0});for(var l=0;l<j.length;++l){var m=jQuery("#language-template").html(),k=j[l];m=m.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",k.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",k.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",k.size).replace("{{LINK}}",k.link),m=jQuery(m),jQuery("#languages").append(m)}}
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list{padding:10px;float:left}#language-list{padding:10px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/codegolf/primary.css?v=f52df912b654"> <div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">{{SIZE}}</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I know the spec says that the output should be empty if no functions are given, but `»+[](a,b)` really could be `ab+ba` as per the _more variables than functions_ rule.

Comment: Can we take the inputs in a different order or more convenient format (i.e. `operator, direction, [[functions], [variables]]`)? Or is either `"operatorDirection[function](variables)"` as string or `[direction,operator,[functions],[variables]]` as list or loose parameters in this exact order and format mandatory?

Comment: Also, could you add some test cases with 3 or more functions? Or is the amount of functions guaranteed to be 0, 1, or 2?

Comment: @KevinCruijsen Yep, you can take input in any convenient form. I'll add more test cases once I have access to my computer (I'm mobile bound until tomorrow)

Comment: May we output `f(x)g(y)zf(y)g(z)xf(z)g(x)y` (with the `zf` and `xf` concatenated like that) for input `»[f,g](x,y,z)`, or do we explicitly need to add a `*` in that case? I would personally allow it and ignore the syntax error, since it's otherwise an annoying (although not hard) edge case to fix. (PS: @Arnauld's JavaScript answer currently outputs `f(x)g(y)zf(y)g(z)xf(z)g(x)y` as well.)

Comment: When there is no operator, concatenation is actually the expected result, so you instead **have** to output like that.

Comment: Suggested test case: `+»(x,y)(foo,bar,baz)`. I think `baz` should be ignored in that case, leading to `foo(x)bar(y)+foo(y)bar(x)`. Could you please confirm that?

Comment: @Arnauld Hmm, that test case definitely fails right now for my program, regardless of what is intended (since it outputs as `foo(x)bar(y)baz)+foo(y)bar(x)baz)+foo(x)bar(y)baz)`..) Will try to fix it.

Comment: Also, what's the expected output for `+«(x,y)(foo,bar,baz)`? (@KevinCruijssen We do agree on that one, but I'm not 100% sure we're right.)

Comment: @Arnauld That's why I was asking for test cases with 3 or more function a few hours ago.. As for `+«(x,y)(foo,bar,baz)`, I personally think it would output as `foo(x)foo(y)+bar(x)bar(y)+baz(x)baz(y)` (although my program currently outputs as `foo(x)+foo(y)+bar(x)+bar(y)+baz(x)+baz(y)`.. >.>)

Comment: I don't find the "in the following method" descriptions clear enough to implement this or decide whether current answers are valid.

Comment: Can we use `<,>` instead of `«,»`?

Comment: @ChasBrown sure!

Comment: Another test case would be `+»[f,g](x)`. What should result when there are more functions than variables?

Comment: @Jono2906 I still don't see any test cases with three or more functions.. What are the intended outputs for `»+[f,g,h](x,y)`, `«+[f,g,h](x,y)`, `»+[f,g,h,i](x,y)` and `«+[f,g,h,i](x,y)`? (And another suggested test case is one with an explicit `*` operator, and an output; since we have to remove them instead of joining by `*`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 63 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
UÇ`θiVεY€…(ÿ)«}ëDg©DIgα+>∍Œ®ùεζεðK'(ýyðå≠i')«]Dg≠iJ}¸˜Xý³gIg*Ā×
```

Four loose inputs in the order `operator, direction, [variables], [functions]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/9HB7wrkdmWHntkY@alrzqGGZxuH9modW1x5e7ZJ@aKWLZ/q5jdp2jzp6j046tO7wznNbz207t/XwBm91jcN7Kw9vOLz0UeeCTHWghliXdBDTq/bQjtNzIg7vPbQ53TNd60jD4en//2tzHdrNFa1UUaGko1RZqRQLZKcBmcn5xUqxAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpSbKWgZF@pw6XkX1oC5IJ5LqfbghL@hx5uTzi3IzPs3NbIR01rHjUs0zi8X/PQ6trDq13SD610ObQeKJt@bqO23aOO3qOTDq07vPPcVrBg8blt57Ye3uCtrnF4b@XhDYeXPupckKkO0goELukgnlftoR2n50Qc3gvUYHR4RTrEMK0jDYen/9c5tM3@0Jb/0dFK2ko6SodWK@lEKyUCWUlKsUBWcn4xkF2cmacUG6ujAFWzG78auDEVQFYlEFcBcR5YaRqyMcSqgQjqKKVDJbRgbkCX0MXiOGR5LNLpQBamoxDyJYl4fI5uK8Iv6DbrY/EvNtdBvYvqXLgAwglp@fkgRyQWgUmIWRCT0VVWYNiDHPZY5ZD8gpDXUcpAD8UKsBqwZxC@ASWG2NhYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
U                   # Pop and store the 1st (implicit) input `operator` in variable `X`
Ç                   # Convert the 2nd (implicit) input `direction` to a list of codepoint
 `                  # Push this codepoint to the stack
  θ                 # Only leave its last digit
   i                # If this digit is 1 (so the direction is "«"):
    V               #  Pop and store the 3rd (implicit) input `variables` in variable `Y`
    ε       }       #  Map over the 4th (implicit) input `functions`:
     Y              #   Push the `variable`-list from variable `Y`
      €…(ÿ)         #   Surround each variable with parenthesis
           «        #   And append it to the current `function` we're mapping
   ë                # Else (so the direction is "»" instead):
    D               #  Duplicate the 3rd (implicit) input `variables`
     g              #  Pop and push the length to get the amount of `variables`
      ©             #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
       D            #  Duplicate this length
        I           #  Push the fourth input `functions`
         g          #  Pop and take its length as well
          α         #  Take the absolute difference between the two amounts
           +        #  And add it to the duplicated amount of `variables`
            >       #  And increase it by 1
             ∍      #  Then extend the duplicated `variables` list to that length
    Œ               #  Get all sublists of this list
     ®ù             #  Only leave the sublists of a length equal to variable `®`
       ε            #  Map each remaining sublist to:
        ζ           #   Create pairs with the 4th (implicit) input `functions`,
                    #   with a default space as filler character if the lengths differ
         ε          #   Map each pair:
          ðK        #    Remove the spaces
          '(ý      '#    Join the pair with a ")" delimiter
          yðå≠i     #    If the current pair did NOT contain a space:
               ')« '#     Append a ")"
]                   # Close all open if-statements and maps
 D                  # Duplicate the resulting list
  g≠i }             # Pop and if its length is NOT 1:
     J              #  Join the inner-most list together to a string
       ¸            # Then wrap it into a list (in case it wasn't a list yet)
        ˜           # And deep flatten the list
         Xý         # Join it by the operator we stores in variable `X`
           ³g       # Get the length of the 3rd input-list `variables`
             Ig     # And the length of the 4th input-list `functions`
               *    # Multiply them with each other
                Ā   # Truthify it (0 remains 0; everything else becomes 1)
                 ×  # And repeat the string that many times
                    # (so it becomes an empty string if either list was empty,
                    #  or remains unchanged otherwise)
                    # (after which this is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: NOTE: Currently fails for test cases with 3+ functions (in both directions) like `»+[f,g,h](x,y)` or `«+[f,g,h](x,y)`. Will fix them and add the explanation after OP clarified what the intended output should be and some 3+ function test cases are added.

Comment: Like Arnauld's answer, your answer does not concatenate the expressions together with an empty string if the operator is `*` (source:`when the operator is *, the expressions are simply concatenated without any symbols`)

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance You're right, noticed that as well. Should be straight-forward to fix. I'm still waiting for those test cases with 3 or more functions though, so I know what the intended solution should be for those before fixing everything.. >.>

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>174</s>  171 bytes

```javascript
(d,o,f,v,g=(f,V=v)=>f?V.map(v=>f+`(${v})`):V)=>f+f&&v+v?(d<'»'?f[1]?f.map(f=>g(f).join``):g(f[0]):v.map((_,i)=>v.map((_,j)=>g(f[j],[v[i++%v.length]])).join``)).join(o):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZJdboMwDMffewoUbSUeKd1eq1Fu0ReEVmgbBuqSalQRMO1EO0LfejHmJFtXVdCPITmxZfuX8HeKRCXl4j3fbEdCLlctD1q6ZJJxplgWUM5mgYJgysOZ/5ZsqELXm9O7D/UJc5jMdMrjw6HyVEiXz@5@54Y8eopDbsp5MM0oB7@QuZhjPQbRYwwTZbL0heUIOAQFmPKoiFmkotzz7pW/Xols@xrHcIBYh0qYuG67kKKU65W/lthIyf6LMId4uERkIUvCSJkLEuswwSAlyHGc8djBJE1Aryk4noNVGOo1hcEpc3cT00KQaeGWPOi8JxpCuGVVyKrRGjRxYHJaAac1WoMmekD2chdBeCnNMltjt0tERjJDNZijD4mEdCv18P/W0UnrscA/rRzVzLTAI3RTdJOegVlxMwTwPpZutpAUeO@UrBTbRHRiDAiT2I6CaufsC@pG3KzL34yP55vhcBsjTI1@A5XxG/QrqLt/bnwd@fcJOlo0e5A@4Myz7pr85R@9qrX9Bg)

#### Commented

```javascript
( d,                              // d   = direction
  o,                              // o   = operator
  f,                              // f[] = list of functions
  v,                              // v[] = list of variables
  g = (f, V = v) =>               // g = helper function taking (f, V[])
    f ?                           //   if f is defined:
      V.map(v =>                  //     for each variable v in V[]:
        f + `(${v})`              //       return f, followed by '(v)'
      )                           //
    :                             //   else:
      V                           //     just return V[] as-is
) =>                              //
  f + f && v + v ?                // if both f[] and v[] are non-empty:
    ( d < '»' ?                   //   if the direction is '«':
        f[1] ?                    //     if there are at least 2 functions:
          f.map(f =>              //       for each function f_i in f[]:
            g(f).join``           //         return 'f_i(v_0)f_i(v_1)...'
          )                       //       end of map()
        :                         //     else:
          g(f[0])                 //       return [ 'f_0(v_0)', 'f_0(v_1)', ... ]
      :                           //   else (the direction is '»'):
        v.map((_, i) =>           //     for each variable at position i:
          v.map((_, j) =>         //       for each variable at position j:
            g(                    //         return [ 'f_j(v_k)' ]
              f[j],               //         where k = i mod v.length
              [v[i++ % v.length]] //         and increment i
            )                     //
          ).join``                //       end of inner map(); join the list
        )                         //     end of outer map()
    ).join(o)                     //   join the final list with the operator
  :                               // else:
    ''                            //   just return an empty string
```

Comment: In the spec, it says `when the operator is *, the expressions are simply concatenated without any symbols`

Comment: [170 bytes using ascii](https://tio.run/##nZJhb4IwEIa/@ytIs0k7Km5fjcC/8AshE9RjENeaYRpg2W9n13Y6Y6rOkVx7l/Z9uLzXOld5s/qodvuJkOvNANFA11xy4IqXEQW@iBSLYkgW4Xu@owrTYEkfPtUXW7LZQh8FMB6rQCV0PfdjP4H0JUvA3IYoLimwsJaVWOJ1LNLnjM2UOaWvvEL9saiZuZ7WGU9VWgXBowq3G1Hu37KMHSE2oZLNfH9YSdHI7SbcShRSMifcIwEuKVnJhnDSVIJkusyxKAhiPG869fCQ5kyvBfMCD29hqdeCjc6Q8V1Iy0CkZVvwyNUlBjLAolpEdRg9hjgigbYMaIfRY4hrrd3kYEsaZbbebsLd2AHISWmghnLyIZAQZytP/1Gaf07OlKfe/igBjSy1txNMC0xztx/W1xL1cAmltZZRMLg0H2vDPhdOiuHgIarRS51cezluwr2e/A73dLAlTrU3pnSY96w1eY95yzpnS9O/gQ8vz9OG2f9o/uXH7Br5zTfzJ@XwDQ "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: representation (previous comment was too long to fit the whole text in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>179</s> <s>190</s> 194 bytes

```python
lambda d,o,F,V,S='%s(%s)':(o*(o>'*')).join([(''.join(S%(u,v)for v in V)for u in F if V),(''.join(map(lambda u,v:v and u and S%(u,v)or v or'',F,(V+V)[i:i+len(V)]))for i in range(len(V)))][d>'<'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTBbsIwDD23X5ELckLDNu1YAZdJ/ABSL10PgbaQCRLUFDT4@c4JHZTRQqdKrp28vOc4cXbHcq3Ve5VPPquN2C5SQVKu@YxHfD6BgaEDwyCkekj1FIbA2MuXlorGFODszQd0zw8s1wU5EKlI5Ny9dWdE5hjzC3YrdrQWwTXhgQiVItTamsax6AIAM6BRELFYhjLYZIpGLGGOWlrqQqhVRs/jjCVxOoUxJKwqM1N@CJMZMiGx73kUhzmBAE0MS21sYKSCxMbCRgtcxh1y2ht55XSz3zY8WnOyRt0yOsIceiCDf0If48a9Kd@4@9rWobtyi2/Uhx2zXUSPq92cRbNsT8vhR3@FW1kdaGW9/MnxQSme3oXu@ftsmhW@UXvtA20p32997vbXWfVG5rWEk8u1djsQxfl3ar96zfyShxfiCrhL294Ph7WHAGuEY0ehlzY1H4F8L/F92@v1U2Q7/tLZoe/hs5KGZFdIVZI00AHENr/6kZmxABLaGIhwgJERaua0JkSFbGOymsOvfgA)

11 bytes lost to fixing a bug.

A function that takes a direction, an operator, a list of functions, and a list of variables. For direction, uses `<,>` instead of `«,»` because utf-x reasons. This assumes that if the direction is `>`, and there are more functions than variables, that we ignore the excess function(s); e.g., `>*[f,g,h],[c,d]) => f(c)g(d)*f(d)g(c)`

Comment: Like Arnauld's answer, your answer does not concatenate the expressions together with an empty string if the operator is `*` (source:`when the operator is *, the expressions are simply concatenated without any symbols`)

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance: Fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 177 bytes

```cs
(d,o,f,v)=>string.Join(o=="*"?"":o,d<61?f.Select(l=>v.Aggregate("",(a,b)=>a+l+$"({b})")):v.Select((x,y)=>string.Concat(v.Select((i,o)=>o>=f.Count?i:f[(y+o)%f.Count]+$"({i})"))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJPb5wwEMXvfIqp1YpxmKUlhxx2MaiqVClVpBy2Ug6IgxfMxhLCEXjRplE@@9b8SXdDpB4Qmvfm/cyMKbpV0enTz0NTxMWjbKmzrW72dHunOxtPRbKo5nclTliSoYp6LpJJDH8Z3aARgl2xlLG1oTK@idIq3KpaFRZrkfTh9/2@VXtpFTJGKGnn4jKog88MX3avnHG@7t8CeKTnM/2HaQpp8exqMs41iaicd2hsqtdVhs@B4V9mJR@xesRyftp4vdElWNVZnKAgObx4AL1sodQtCJDZt3wzK@ZpFKIchAA/8yEFxmA9SuFvsx0RyId2OXSG28Nu4uIQFUN3CpFLXPM3ZuWWbbVpukUgIlfeNqU63lfo5z6HFUQ83D7V2qJP/giYGe7RclerJeMCgA4QwHsoH6GLpsUp4cOjahUeQSRwhE/DCNyNOvwC06APrbbqTjcKK3QbI7ckOg9F52/jfAPeqzcum8VBVpiOOt3kw6XSH3cjm9lLshwvy6v/tK7eeZfOvwPIyg9u/PVjzjv9BQ)